# WPF: why my ComboBox Selected Value Command return wrong value

Tags: wpf, command

I want to be able to send my `Command` the current `ComboBox` value.

This is my `ComboBox`

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ConcurrentFilesList}"
          SelectedIndex="0">
          <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                  <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ConcurrentFilesValueChangedCommand}"
                                                           CommandParameter="ComboBox.SelectedValue"/>
          </i:EventTrigger>
                 </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

This `ItemSource` ConcurrentFilesList is `List` of numbers.

```
CanExecute

public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
    int num = (int)parameter;
    return true;
}
```

But my `Parameter` is `string`

**EDIT**

My parameter is `"ComboBox.SelectedIndex"` and not a number.

Comment: I mean that my Parameter is "ComboBox.SelectedIndex"

Comment: Instead of the string `ComboBox.SelectedValue` you probably want to assign a Binding to the CommandParameter property. See the answer to the duplicate question.